# Non-abelian Groups of Order $p^3$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, p-groups

I am trying to show that a non-abelian group $G$ of order $p^3$ is isomorphic to one of two groups constructed on page 48 of [these](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GT.pdf) group theory notes (see examples 3.14 and 3.15 on that page).

Here is some of my work so far:

> Since $G$ is a $p$-group, it must have non-trivial center; but, as $G$ is non-abelian, the order of $Z := Z(G)$ must be $p$. This means that $G/Z \cong \Bbb{Z}_p \times \Bbb{Z}_p$, so $G/Z$ is generated by two elements. Let $x,y$ be the elements whose images (under the canonical projection map) in $G/Z$ generate $G/Z$. Since $G/Z$ is abelian (all $p^2$ groups are abelian), $[x,y] \in Z$. If $[x,y]$ were the identity, then $G$ would actually be abelian, so $[x,y] \neq 1$, in which case the only possible order of it is $p$. Hence, $Z = \langle [x,y] \rangle$.

At this point, my idea was to break up the problem into two cases: both $x$ and $y$ have order $p$, or at least one has order For the first case, I thought I was basically finished. I showed that $x$, $y$ and $[x,y]$ satisfied the three defining relations in example 3.15:

$$a^p = b^p = c^p = 1 \text{ , } ab = cac^{-1} \text{ , } [b,a] = 1 = [b,c],$$

where, in my situation, $a = x$, $b = [x,y]$, and $c =y$. But then it quickly occured to me that $[x,y] \in \langle x,y \rangle$, so the commutator cannot be the third generator.

As for the case, I wasn't able to come up with anything. I have been working on this problem for a rather long time; I could use some guidance. Initially I was vainly following the hint in the back of the book; but then someone in the chatroom kindly pointed out that the author made a false claim in the hint.

Comment: There is no issue; generating sets/relations need not be as small as possible. Note that even in the original description, you do not *actually* need $b$, since $b$ can be replaced with $b=a^{-1}cac^{-1}$ (from the equality $ab=cac^{-1}$), and so you can describe the group using just two generators. That is, $b\in\langle a,c\rangle$ in the original description, so there is no problem with you having your third “generator” be in the subgroup generated by the first two.

Comment: Your final paragraph seem to be incomplete. “As for the case”.... what case? Where one of $x$ and $y$ has order $p^2$? Say $x$ has order $p^2$ and $y$ has order $p$. Since $x$ and $y$ project to different things, you must have $\langle x\rangle\cap \langle y\rangle = \{e\}$, and so $\langle x\rangle\langle y\rangle = G$ (by a simple counting argument). So every element is of the form $x^ay^b$, $0\leq a\lt p^2$, $0\leq b\lt p$. Show that $[x,y]\in\langle x^p\rangle$.

Comment: $[x,y]$ lies in $\langle x,y\rangle$; but, *it can be taken as third generator*! unlike in abelian groups, the third generator is not necessarily outside the subgroup $\langle x,y\rangle$. [In fact, $\langle x,y\rangle$ is whole group $G$ in your case, whether $o(x)=p^2,o(y)=p$ or both have order $p$, or both have order $p^2$! Thus, the third generator *has to be in* $G=\langle x,y\rangle$; where is problem? $G$ is non-abelian!

Comment: @Beginner "unlike in abelian groups"? Generating sets **never** have to be minimal. For example, the following is a perfectly fine presentation of an abelian group (the Klein 4-group, which can be generated by two elements as well): $\langle x,y,z\mid x^2=y^2=z^2=1, xy=z, xy=yx, xz=zx, yz=zy\rangle$.

Comment: yes; that is fine. My rough comment was, in *finite abelian groups*, the usual generating sets are minimal ones (of course all elements of $G$ form generating set.) The user193319 asked this problem of picking third generator outside $\langle x,y\rangle$; I thought, he might be considering situations of abelian groups. In (one of) the proof of structure of finite abelian groups, generators are chosen in such fashion.

Comment: @Beginner: Of course any finite generating set can be reduced to minimal ones. Here, perhaps, it would be more germane to point out that the presentation he is trying to match *also* has the issue that one of the given generators lies in the subgroup generated by the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) $G/Z(G)$ is generated by $xZ(G)$ and $yZ(G)$; $Z(G)$ is generated by $[x,y]$ (also note $Z(G)=G'$).

(2) Suppose that not both $x,y$ have order $p$. This implies two cases: $o(x)=p^2$, $o(y)=p$ or $o(x)=o(y)=p^2$. [The case $o(x)=p, o(y)=p^2$ has considered, can you see?]

(2.1) Suppose $o(x)=p^2$ and $o(y)=p$. Then $\langle y\rangle$ is subgroup of order $p$, and $\langle y\rangle\cap Z(G)=1$.

Since $xZ(G)$ is of order $p$, so $x^p\in Z(G)$, and $x^p\neq 1$ (since $o(x)=p^2)$, so without loss, we can take $x^p=[x,y]$. So $\langle x\rangle$ is group of order $p^2$, it has unique subgroup of order $p$ namely $\langle x^p\rangle$ which is $\langle [x,y]\rangle$, which is $Z(G)$, and $\langle y\rangle$ intersects with this trivialy; i.e. $\langle x\rangle\cap\langle y\rangle=1$. So $G=\langle x\rangle.\langle y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$, where $x,y$ satisfy relations (which perhaps you want)
$$x^{p^2}=1, y^p=1, x^p=[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy \mbox{ i.e. } x^{1+p}=y^{-1}xy.$$

(2.2) Suppose $o(x)=o(y)=p^2$. Then point is *we can modify one of these two generators to get a new generator of order $p$*. How to do this? This requires commutator calculus: since $[x,y]\in Z(G)$, so $[x,y]$ commutes with both $x$ and $y$. You can prove that $(xy)^n=x^ny^n[y,x]^{\binom{n}{2}}$. (Prove this, use induction on $n$.)
Now we use this. Since $o(X)=o(y)=p^2$, and $x^p,y^p\in Z(G)=\langle [x,y]\rangle$, without loss, we can assume that 
$$x^p=y^p=[x,y].$$
Then $$(yx^{-1})^p=y^px^{-p}[x^{-1},y]^{\binom{p}{2}}.$$
Since $[x^{-1},y]$ is a member of $G'=Z(G)$, it is of order $p$ and for odd $p$, the integer $\binom{p}{2}=p(p-1)/2$ is multiple of $p$, so $[x^{-1},y]^{\binom{p}{2}}=1$. Also $y^px^{-p}=1$ (why?) Thus we get 
$$(yx^{-1})^p=1.$$
So, instead of $y$ you take new generator $y_1=yx^{-1}$; this is of order $p$, and we move in case (2.1), which is done!

Comment: Regarding case 2.1, why can we without loss of generality assume $x^p = [x,y]$? You also make this assumption about $x^p$ and $y^p$ in case 2.2., so hopefully you could clarify that, too.

Comment: Also, why does $Z = G'$?

Comment: @user193319 Write $[x,y]=x^{bp}$; this is possible since $[x,y]\in\langle x\rangle$ and $|x|=p^2$. Also, $b$ is invertible mod. $p$, because $[x,y]\ne 1$. Thus, there exists a multiplicative inverse $c$ of $b$ mod. $p$. Now, because $x$ and $y$ commute with $[x,y]$, we have $[x,y^c]=[x,y]^c$. Furthermore, $[x,y]^c=x^p$. Replacing $y$ with $y^c$, we get the desired equality.

Comment: @user193319: $G’$ is nontrivial because $G$ is not abelian; $G/G’$ is abelian, and any normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $G/N$ is abelian must contain $G’$. Therefore, $G’\subseteq Z(G)$, and since $Z(G)$ is order $p$ and $G’$ is of order greater than $1$, the two must be equal.